# Randomly choose different pin until you reach target

Tags: python, probability, infinite-loop

I am trying to create a program that that runs ten times that simulates someone randomly selecting a number 0-10 until they land on they guess the correct number 9. They must make sure to keep track of numbers that they already guessed so they don't guess them again. I need the size of the list to hold the number of guesses for each of the ten times the game was ran needed to reach 9.

The problem is i've ran into an infinite loop and can't get this to work. Does anyone have any advice? Thanks.

```
list1= []
for x in range(10):
    guess= None
    while guess != 9:
        while guess in list1:
            guess= rd.randint(0,10)
            list1.append(guess)
    size= len(list1)
    print(size)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is:

```
 while guess in list1:
```

Its this while loop. For the first iteration(when x=0),we know that guess!=9, so it'll encounter this next while loop: `while guess in list1`, now since list1 is empty as you have initialised at the top, it does not ever go into the loop and thus
`while guess != 9:` goes into an infinite loop. I've modified your code a little bit to get the solution:

```
import random
for i in range(10):
    lst = []
    guess = 0
    while guess!=9:
        guess = random.randint(0,10)
        if guess not in lst:
            lst.append(guess)
    print(len(lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

For a shorter code, you can simply use the `random.shuffle` method, like this:

```py
import random

for i in range(10):
    cards = list(range(11))  # cards are in range [0:10]
    random.shuffle(cards)
    idx = cards.index(9)  # index of 9 number
    lst = cards[:idx+1]  # take only 9-number and before
    print(len(lst))
```

This code avoid also `while` loop and is more determinist.